# Python - Pull most visited store, if tied pull store where most was spent. If tied at 1 then pull most recently visited store

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, if-statement

I am working in Python with a dataset that looks like the following
Original Dataset:

[image: Dataset]

Where
Card Number - Unique client identifier

Store Number - Unique store identifier

Count - Count of times a unique store has been visited by a unique client

Sum_Check Subtotal Accrued - Sum a client has spent at a unique store

Max_Date - Last time the unique client visited the unique store

I am trying to turn this into a dataframe that contains the Card Number and Store Number with the following logic applied in this order:

1. the most visits
2. if the amount of visits is tied at 2+, I want the Store Number with the highest spend
3. If the amount of visits is tied at 1 between multiple locations I want the most recently visited location.

So the final output should look as follows:
[image: Desired Output]

Currently my code looks like this

```
#sorting the values so that the most visited locations are at the bottom of the group followed by the highest spend. 
#This allows for in the event of a tie for the algo to go to the check subtotal sum field and take the largest value
df = df.sort_values(['Card Number', 'Count', 'Sum_Check Subtotal Accrued', 'Max_Date']).drop_duplicates('Card Number', keep='last')

#dropping fields we no longer need now that our dataset is summarized
df=df.drop(['Count', 'Sum_Check Subtotal Accrued', 'Max_Date], axis = 1)
```

Which was working until the 3rd logic point was added which requires me to pull the most recent visit if tied at 1. I have tried adding the "Max_Date" field to the above code. However, the "Sum_Check Subtotal Accrued" field doesn't allow this to work for the clients tied at 1.

I am guessing some sort of If statement can solve this but am conceptually stuck on how to approach in this way

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got it:

```py
import pandas as pd

CN = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
SN = [111, 222, 111, 222, 444, 22, 55, 22, 222, 888]
Count = [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
SCSA = [40, 100, 50, 20, 30, 20, 50, 2, 200, 100]
Date = ["1/2/2021", "2/2/2021", "3/2/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/11/2022", "6/1/2018", "7/11/2022", "3/4/2020" ,"1/2/2019"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Card":CN, "Store":SN, "Count":Count, "SCSA":SCSA, "Date":Date})

cards = df.Card.unique()
storeList = []

# Loop through each card uniquely, checking for their max values
for x in cards:
    Card = df[df.Card == x]
    countMax = Card.Count.max()
    dateMax = Card.Date.max()
    
    # If there is only one store with the max visits, add it to the list
    if len(Card[Card.Count == countMax]) < 2:
        storeList.append(Card.Store[Card.Count == countMax].values[0])
    # If the number of visits is >= 2 and there is more than 1 store with this number of visits...
    elif (countMax >= 2) and (len(Card[Card.Count == countMax]) > 1):
        scsaMax = Card[Card.Count == countMax].SCSA.max() # Find the highest spending of the stores that were visited the most
        storeList.append(Card.Store[Card.SCSA == scsaMax].values[0]) # add the store with the most spending of the store that were visited the most
    # Otherwise, just add the most recently visited store to the list
    else:        
        storeList.append(Card.Store[Card.Date == dateMax].values[0])
        
        
pd.DataFrame({"Card Number":cards, "Store Number":storeList})
```

Output:

```
Card Number Store Number
1   111
2   111
3   444
4   22
5   22
```

I changed some of the visit counts and SCSA values to make sure it was still printing out what I expected it to, seems to be right now.

Comment: Card #4 should be 22. Since the client visited 2 stores, 1 time each logical point #2 should be ignored and we skip to logical point #3 where we pull the location that was visited most recently. Sorry for not clarifying that earlier.

Comment: Try the new edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(df.sort_values(['Count','Max_Date','Sum_Check Subtotal Accrued'],ascending = [0,0,0])
.groupby('Card Number')[['Card Number','Store Number']]
.head(1)
.sort_values('Card Number'))
```

Comment: This gives me the same result as the code I posted. If a Card Number has visited multiple stores only once then it should be pulling the most recently visited store. ex. Card#4 output should be Store#22 since it was visited on 7/11/22. This code pulls Store#55 for Card#4.

Comment: should be fixed now